# Allow linked external accounts to grant commenting privileges

Tags: feature-request, comments, user-accounts, privileges

I've seen relevant 'answers' from people qualified to answer questions on open source projects deleted simply because those qualified people didn't have enough magic internet points to ask clarifying questions in comments. Yes, comments are not what answers are for. Yes, reviewers generally don't have the ability to move answers to comments. Yes, this horse has been beaten again and again. No, the status quo is *not okay*.

Specifically, the problem is a dependence on the ebb and flow of social cues for a user to establish reputation when they ought to be allowed to provide relevant feedback as soon as possible. This is not a problem on meta, as the reputation requirement is only 5. Everywhere else, it's at 50.

This is the thought (described in a Stack Overflow-centric way for ease of digestion):

Connect question tags with projects located on blessed open source hosts (e.g. GitHub and BitBucket) and check new SO users' linked accounts for collaborator and contributor status on those projects. If the user checks out, they get commenting privileges on questions with those tags regardless of low initial reputation. The process of linking these to enable commenting would require a bit of user initiative and display suitable warnings/instructions as they go through it. The likelihood of such users being 'noisy' is significantly diminished, and further having collaborator status in a project and genuine interest in making the project successful thus is not likely something that would significantly contribute to noisiness.

This leaves open the following issues up for discussion, among others:

- The metric used to see if a user 'checks out'

  - Through what process would trust be established between accounts? This would necessarily be context-specific.
  - For example: how would one determine one's expertise in a particular area of biology from e.g. an OpenScienceFramework account? This kind of thing might be easier for Stack Exchanges like Stack Overflow where questions and projects tend to follow the same delineation.
- New projects not having relevant tags
- The blessed sites from which accounts may be linked for which StackExchange sites

There are likely well known inherent flaws in the Stack Exchange system (technical, social, etc.) that hurt efforts such as this, but, c'est la vie. Just a thought.

In case it isn't blazingly obvious, **this isn't something I've personally experienced**. It's something I've watched happen and been utterly disappointed with.

Comment: Ask any high-rep user what their success rate on comments asking for clarification is... If you think you know the answer, best just post it; if you're wrong the asker's a lot more motivated to tell you than if you post a comment.

Comment: This isn't about me - this is about people who I've been looking over the shoulders of.

Comment: So next time you're doing that, tell 'em what I just said.

Comment: @Shog9 I don't believe that a defense of the status quo is an optimal solution to a problem.

Comment: I don't have a solution to the problem; interactive problem definition is kinda basic human nature. I do try to be decent enough about telling folks when they're beating their heads against a wall though. If you want clarification, repeat back what you THINK the problem is along with your proposed solution - folks will respond.

Comment: @Shog9 Certainly that's a valid approach within a system when one has given up on trying to improve the system. Your comment, however, is like an X-Y *answer*; the problem is that qualified users have to deal with formalities. The solution being suggested as a counter is: qualified users should have to deal with formalities, in response to the unasked irrelevant question, "Why does StackExchange work this way?"

Comment: You're missing the root problem here: requests for clarification have an *abysmal* success rate. Even if we solved the problems of comment abuse, even if we could let anyone on the net post comments anywhere they wanted... We'd mostly just have succeeded in increasing the number of people wasting their time, while removing the current motivation - irritating though it may be - to try and answer. Everyone loses.

Comment: @Shog9 And it is less wasteful to take the time to write out a longer and thought out answer making a boatload of assumptions? I have a hard time believing that.

Comment: That's your call; your time is yours to do with as you wish. If your level of confidence is low, then find a question you *do* understand. Either way, *someone* gets an answer.

Comment: @Shog9 Again, this isn't about me. I have the privileges I want already. It's about people who want to successfully answer questions about their projects on e.g. SO, about people who can't make a user connection or establish anything about themselves because there's some initially-non-merit based limit in their way. They don't get a voice without first getting indoctrinated in ways they *only* need for their first few harder months, and that's just *sad*.

Comment: Sure they get a voice. But they gotta have something useful to say. Look... Read the linked duplicate.

Comment: @Shog9 I have, and I understand it. I'm not denying the correctness of anything that's been claimed thus far. What I *am* denying is that it is the best course of action, and I *am* claiming that it's worth finding a better alternative, regardless of whether it's my flawed suggestion above or not..

Comment: Finding a *better* solution is hard. Always open to suggestions, but... Do your homework first. No one here is interested in solving a problem and causing a bigger one.

Comment: @Shog9 I don't see what it is that I should've done my homework on. You've literally provided me a single subjective determination that only applies to users who have already been through the gauntlet of the status quo. Moreover, the answer below demonstrates grade-A misunderstanding of the suggestion. This is in no way a duplicate of the `Why?` question linked, as it is a discussion made with the understanding of that linked post (which I've already reviewed several times in the past months). What *exactly* should I have been aware of prior to starting this discussion?

Comment: You should be aware of why this restriction is in place - everything described in the linked question. Your proposed solution does nothing to address the problem of noise from folks unfamiliar with Stack Exchange, and in fact proposes familiarity with a system groaning under the weight of its own noisy comments as an acceptable alternative.

Comment: @Shog9 No, it *doesn't*. It still *requires* a user to go through and find a way to actually link the accounts. It isn't like a user will immediately upon getting on StackExchange have their accounts magically linked.

Comment: Instead of protesting, edit your post to address the problems.

Comment: @Shog9 I did, shortly after each response in which something relevant came up. Or would you have preferred a complete rewrite of the question?

Comment: Note that your first line or so starts off sounding as though you *blame* high-rep users for deleting non-answers... this is unreasonable, and triggers an instinctive defensiveness by those who consider that they're just doing the best they can with what they've got. If that's not what you mean, I strongly recommend reworking.

Comment: @NathanTuggy It isn't. I've been trying to make it clear throughout that I have no particular target, and that it's the overall system I take issue with. Given that the distinction is perhaps too subtle for the audience, yes, I'll change it (however futile it might be). Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: The potential value of this system would be in allowing *contributors* to projects hosted publicly to better *support those projects* on Stack Exchange sites. Which is a reasonable idea at face value, but there are a *lot* of missing pieces here: we need some means of connecting your work on a 3rd-party site to relevant posts here. That's... A non-trivial problem.

Answer (score 4):

Users have hard times appropriately asking for clarification already. It seems that way just like Shog9 said so:

> You're missing the root problem here: requests for clarification have an abysmal success rate. Even if we solved the problems of comment abuse, even if we could let anyone on the net post comments anywhere they wanted... We'd mostly just have succeeded in increasing the number of people wasting their time, while removing the current motivation - irritating though it may be - to try and answer. Everyone loses. – Shog9♦

This network is prone to extreme comment abuse. We have seen the rules already: no "thanks" or "+/-1" or just anything that doesn't relate or improve the current post. The comments a lot of times lead to lengthy discussions that require the intervention of a moderator or more. Sometimes even, the post gets locked just because of lousy commenting.

That is just from users we have told the rules to a million times and are under our rules. Now we are speaking about non-users who probably have no knowledge of our commenting rules or simply how to comment. Maybe this site's ways of commenting just destroys our rules and if they pass the user, now we got one more user to worry about and clean up after.

Now as Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange in general are viewed millions of times per day (I think), cleaning up lousy, unneeded comments will take longer than clearing up Stack Overflow's Close Votes queue. Then the posts and owners will be barraged with tens to hundreds of useless comments that the owner or anyone else to answer. Except Google.

We cannot rely on other sites to tell use whether people are qualified or not. Their actions on Stack Exchange will though. So if you wanna comment, show us you can and we will give you that easily abused privilege. Even better, get 200 rep on one site you are awesome at and get to comment on every single site on Stack Exchange the second you join.

TL;DR: Humans are humans. Users can't handle comments under ***Stack Exchange's*** strict rules, why would other sites allow random people to clutter out posts and turn our moderators into clean-up crews?